# flask reactjs gulp setup auto reload

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, gulp

I have flask reactjs setup project that I cloned it below URL and its working fine.

https://github.com/tonmcg/flask-react-example

Now I made some changes to the below file by adding a console statement -

https://github.com/tonmcg/flask-react-example/blob/master/scripts/main.js

```
var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Catalyst.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function(){
    var domain = {
      'Sepal Width': [1.0, 5.0],
      'Sepal Length': [3.5, 8.5],
      'Petal Width': [0.0, 3.5],
      'Petal Length': [0.0, 7.5]
    }
    var dimensions= Object.keys(domain);
    var features = {};
    for(var j=0; j < dimensions.length; j++){
      var key = dimensions[j];
      features[key] = 0.5 * (domain[key][0] + domain[key][1]) ;
    }
    console.log('domain = ', domain)
    console.log('features = ', features)
    return {
      domain: domain,
      features: features
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            <Features domain={this.state.domain} features={this.state.features} 
                      linkState={this.linkState} />
            <div className='col-md-10'>
              <BarChart features={this.state.features}/>
              <ScatterNav features={this.state.features}
                          domain={this.state.domain}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )}
});
```

Now, when I run 'gulp' to build all the tasks it runs the server and I'm able to view the console log statements.

Im trying to understand the workflow, should I start my flask server to test the changes or should I run the gulp command.

Generally(for normal CSS, HTML, Javascript project), I do a auto reload of the flask server and the code changes will be reflected?

How can I set the flask project to autoload as well make the gulp run its changes.

Comment: Basically this is not Python's business. When you add something like `reload` to your front end, it is totally a front end business. I'm not familiar with that lib `browser-sync`, but I guess it is just a timer which refreshing your static resources.

Comment: thanks, so, every time, I need to run the gulp command, rebuild the static sources and restart the python server?

Comment: I am not sure. Generally you needn't do anything. `browser-sync`'s `reload` should provide your front end the ability to refresh static resources automatically. That's very common during the development. When I was developing a front end, the mechanism of auto refreshing is an infinite callback stack, it keep asking the server about the resources. I think you can have a look about the requests from the front end.